# illegal character, Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, illegal-characters

I am trying to run jquery through a rails app. I have the edit information in a popup window and i want to change that to show information after they click update. It should work but this line

```
$(".edit_business).append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:file => 'businesses/show')) %>");
```

is throwing an illegal character issue. This code is in my update.js.erb file. The escape_javascript is there but it's throwing an error in my console.

Comment: could you show the generated code?

Comment: ... and the error thrown while you're at it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you actually missing that quote?

```
$(".edit_business").append(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a quote in $(".edit_business")

Answer (score 1):

```
(".edit_business)
```

shoud be

```
(".edit_business")
```

Answer (score 0):

I often just use `render(:file => filename).to_json`